# Declaring functions part two

Tags: c++

Guys please help me again with my program. I changed the order of codes in it. Please check what is wrong with my codes. It runs but it doesn't perform the task it should do. It should compute the total of the grades inputted by the user and show the corresponding remarks. Unfortunately, it doesn't work :( please help me

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

void computePG(int& PG);
void Remark(int PG);

    int x, y, z, w, p;
    int prelimGrade,yourRemark,PG;
    int preliminaryGrade; 

int main()
{
    int pGrade;

 cout<<"Programmed by: Katrina G. Gozo, 1ISC";
 cout<<endl<<"\nDate: Aug. 23,2013";
 cout<<endl<<"\nThis program intends to compute the PG and make the necessary remarks";

 cout<<"\n\nPlease enter your score on quiz 1 ";
 cin>>x;

 cout<<"\nPlease enter your score on quiz 2 ";
 cin>>y;

 cout<<"\nPlease enter your score on quiz 3 ";
 cin>>z;

 cout<<"\nPlease enter your score on prelims ";
 cin>>p;


computePG(pGrade);
Remark(pGrade);


getch();
}

void computePG(int& PG)
{
    PG = x/30 * 20 + y/50 * 20 + z/40 * 20 + w/100 * 40;
    cout << "\nYour prelim grade is " << PG;

} 

void Remark(int PG)
{
     if (PG>=90)
        cout<<"A." <<endl;
     else if (PG>=80)
          cout<<"B."<<endl;
     else if (PG>=70)
          cout<<"C."<<endl;
     else if (PG>=60)
          cout<<"D."<<endl;
     else 
          cout<<"E."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Time to learn how to use your debugger

Comment: I hope that's YOUR name in the output!

Comment: What do you expect it to do and what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely running afoul of integer arithmetic. Note: when dividing an integer by another integer, you get an integer result (rounded towards zero).

So you'll want to use `double` as the type of `PG` and `pGrade`, and make the constants in `computePG` floating points numbers as well, by writing them as `30.0`, `20.0`, etc.

Comment: E.g. `29/30*20` is 0. OTOH, `29*20/30` is 19.

Comment: Please elaborate further Sir, I'm just a begginner

Comment: An integer only cares about what the whole part of the number, so there can be rounding errors when you divide, even if you don't care about what's after the decimal.  For example, if you were to use `int i = 1/2;`, `i` would be equal to 0, not 1, because it just drops the .5.  As I mentioned in my answer, using a double will fix this problem, but I'd recommend you become familiar with the different numeric types in c++.

Comment: @Namfuak Using a double is not enough, since the entire calculation expression will still be on the integer level. She'll also have to turn all those constants into doubles (by appending `.0` to each).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a double for your variable "PG," that way you'll have adequate decimal accuracy.

Also, you may want to avoid global variables in the future, because I'm guessing it's how you made this error - you never assign a value to `w` before using it, which means it is assigned the value 0 by the compiler and may be what is screwing up your result.

Comment: `w` is a global and thus 0-initialized; its use is actually well-defined and it doesn't contribute anything to the calculation. Which doesn't mean that I endorse the globals, of course.

Comment: I never knew that, which shows you how much I use globals.  I'll update my answer.  It's possible this is still her problem if she expects w to have a useful value.